# Find all records of a certain type in Polymorphic table using ActiveRecord in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have a table Category that is a polymorphic model for a bunch of other models. For instance

> model Address has shipping, billing,
> home, work category
>
> model Phone has home, mobile, work,
> fax category
>
> model Product has medical, it
> equipment, automotive, aerospace, etc
> categories.

What I want to be able to do is something like

Product.all_categories and get and array of all categories that are specific to this model.

Of course I can do something like this for each model in question:

```
Category.select("name").where("categorizable_type = ?","address")
```

Also pace_car - which is rails 3 ready, allows me to do something like this:

```
Category.for_category_type(Address)
```

But I was wondering if there is a more straightforward / elegant solution to this problem using Active Record iteself - without relying on a gem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything built-in to ActiveRecord to give you this, but you could set up that `for_category_type` method in one line of code in your Category controller:

```
scope :for_category_type, lambda { |class_name| where("categorizable_type = ?", class_name) }
```

Comment: Dammit, it's always the simplest solution right in front of you, isn't. I guess i stopped thinking after the 18 hours crash coding session.  Came to me the next day as well, that I forgot about scopes.  Thank you anyways.